# Query expansion, which term to expand?

Tags: wordnet, sql-execution-plan

Suppose we have a query with the following term:

```
A and B and C and D
```

Now suppose the query is too restrictive, and we want to expand the query, but is there already a way to find which term to expand. Of course, it makes sense to expand the term which is limiting the search space.

My question is there already a existing procedure to find out which term to expend during query expansion

Comment: http://lucene-qe.sourceforge.net/ Is this something that would be beneficial?

Comment: I'm somewhat new to this field of IR, if it does what i want to do, i would want to try it

Comment: @Chris.Stover, is there tutorial about how to use it??

Comment: None that I know of. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful